# Does ChromeDriver support Rotatable for mobileEmulation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing a web app with Selenium 2.44 and ChromeDriver 2.13. I'm using Chromes mobile emulation to mock connecting from a mobile device. I need to change the screen orientation mid test from portrait to landscape and I can't seem to get it working.

Sample code for trying to augment WebDriver to Rotatable is below but it is throwing a ClassCastException when trying to cast to Rotatable. Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or if ChromeDriver does not support rotation?

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.Rotatable;
import org.openqa.selenium.ScreenOrientation;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddRotatable;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(
              "webdriver.chrome.driver",
              "Path/To/chromedriver.exe"
        );

        Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 4");

        Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<>();
        chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ROTATABLE, true);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://m.rte.ie");

        // Try and rotate
        Augmenter augmenter = new Augmenter();
        augmenter.addDriverAugmentation(CapabilityType.ROTATABLE, new AddRotatable());
        WebDriver augmentedDriver = augmenter.augment(driver);
        ScreenOrientation currentOrientation = ((Rotatable) augmentedDriver).getOrientation();
        System.out.println(String.format("Current Orientation is: %s", currentOrientation));

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

It appears as though Chrome supports switch orientation as is documented here: (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) if you look at the section on, 'Swap dimensions'. I have tried this manually in the browser and it works fine. Just wondering if ChromeDriver does not support the Rotatable interface, is there a way to update the screen dimensions on the fly?

Comment: Looking for the same answer..

Answer (score 4):

It was a tough one. Hope this saves a decent amount of effort for someone. As for now, ChromeDriver only supports portrait orientation in mobile emulation mode. There are no workarounds whatsoever to pass it as an option and no ability to trigger from javascript either.

Yet, there is a solution that seems to work for me. What you need to do is simply start the ChromeDriver with userAgent option which represents your device. For instance, here is what it looks like for iPad emulation:

```
Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();

String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 " +
                "(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--user-agent=" + userAgent);
options.addArguments("window-size=1039,859");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Also, you might want to set the dimensions that resemble the emulated device. It's a bit tricky, since only the window size could be set in ChromeOptions. And again, with the use of this tool: [Chrome viewport dimensions plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewport-dimensions/kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk?hl=en-US) you can find the correct ratio for your resolution. In my case, viewport's 1024x768 correspond to 1039x859 of window-size.

P.S. it could be done only on driver start. There is no possibility to change the orientation on the fly

Comment: Passing by to say thank you. I found a Chromium bug for this that was archived. Looks like in 2020 this is still true.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that it accepts "deviceOrientation" as a *capacity* with values "portrait" and "landscape", but unfortunately this is not yet implemented.

Waiting for the same answer.